# JAVA XmlRpcClient

Tags: java, xmlrpcclient

I am using this code to connect server, but get error:

```
pms.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
server.setconfig(config);
enter code here   ^
  symbol:   method setconfig(XmlRpcClientConfigImpl)
  location: variable server of type XmlRpcClient



import java.util.*;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientConfigImpl;
//import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientConfig;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.common.*;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.*;
import java.net.*;

public class pms {
    public static void main (String [] args) {

        try {
            String UserName = "123";
            String Password = "123";
            String pKey     = "123";
            Vector params = new Vector();
            params.addElement(UserName);
            params.addElement(Password);
            params.addElement(pKey);
            XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
            config.setServerURL(new URL(" https://wubook.net/xrws/"));
            XmlRpcClient server = new XmlRpcClient();
            server.setconfig(config);

            Object result = server.execute("acquire_token",params);

            System.out.println(result);

            System.out.println("Hello World");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: paste error stack trace properly

Answer (score 0):

i think  it should be `server.setConfig(config)`not`server.setconfig(config)`

you can import

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientConfigImpl;

only 
and here is the dependancy

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
<artifactId>xmlrpc-client</artifactId>
<version>3.1.3</version>
```

it work fine and the output [image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code  server.setcongfig should be setConfig (capitlization)